# If $A$ is nilpotent, $f_A$ defined by $f_A(X) = XA-AX$ is also nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ be a nilpotent matrix.  Define a linear map $f_A:M_n(\mathbb C) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb C)$ by $f_A(X) = XA-AX$.  Prove that the eigenvalues of $f_A$ are all 0.

I tried to solve it by showing $f_A$ is nilpotent, and noticed that the $n$-fold composition $f_A^n(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}A^kXA^{n-k}$. But I do not have any idea as to how to use these properties to solve the problem.

I would appreciate if you could give a clue.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in that. You should be getting higher and higher powers of $A$, not of $X$.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo.

Comment: Just for the sake of new information, this is actually related to Lie algebras! If you consider a matrix as an endomorphism, you can make this vector space into a lie algebra by defining: [X,Y] = XY -YX, as you did. What you have shown is that nilpotency is invariant under the bracket operation!

Comment: @Pteromys Did you find a solution? Please help if you got it

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara As in the accepted answer, if you take $n$ big enough relative to $m$, all summands in my original post are the zero matrix.

Comment: @Pteromys Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is nilpotent $\Rightarrow A^m=0$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$.

If $m=2$ what is $f^3_A(X)$?
If $m=3$ what is $f^5_A(X)$?
If $m=4$ what is $f^7_A(X)$?
Can you generalize?